# Drupal Contexual filter doubles results on multilanguage site

Tags: drupal-8

I have a view in a multi-languages site on Drupal 8 which worked fine.

When I submitted content on the second language items starts showing twice. I believe I have to pass the language on the contextual filter but I don't know-how

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by going to view-->advanced--->other---->query string and then clicking on distinct